# Rivescript: Using Keyword Triggers in Conditional Responses

Tags: javascript, chatbot, rivescript

I am working on a chatbot with Rivescript and am trying to use keyword triggers in conditional responses.

In the [tutorial](https://www.rivescript.com/docs/tutoria) on the site, it is explained that you can use...

> `[*]` optionals to ignore parts of a message...

This works fine in the initial prompt `+ [*] you [*]` but when I try to use this method to capture *any* response that contains `yes` or `no` as part of a conditional response it seems to break it? I don't get an error code, but it simply defaults to `- So, back to the matter at hand...` as a response.

```
  + [*] you [*]
  - Oh, so we're talking about me now?

  + *
  % oh so we are talking about me now
  * <star> == [*] no [*]  => Whatever...
  * <star> == [*] yes [*] => This should be fun.{topic=myself}
  - So, back to the matter at hand...
```

If this were to work I would expect the conversation to go, for example:

```
User: What do you do?
Bot: Oh, so we're talking about me now?
User: Yes, I suppose so
Bot: This should be fun.
```

So, is there any way to use conditional responses without an *explicit* user input? But rather one that just *contains* a certain response? I imagine this is a problem with using the `*` in two instances, both as `<star>` and `[*]`, but can't work out a solution within the framework? Maybe I'm missing something? I've also tried using `*yes*` and `*no*`.

Update:

Perhaps, it is a problem with the conditional operator I am using? Maybe `==` is not the correct method for comparing two values when I am simply trying to find out whether one is *contained* in the other? I've since found the  [Working Draft](https://www.rivescript.com/wd/RiveScript) but no luck here either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to get in touch with [Noah Petherbridge](https://www.kirsle.net/) who worked on Rivescript  and who very kindly took the time to correct my understanding:

```
+ [*] you [*]
- So you are talking about me now?

+ [*] (yes|no) [*]
% so you are talking about me now
* <star> == yes => yes answer
* <star> == no => no answer
- default, shouldn't happen answer
```

For some reason I guess I assumed that I couldn't use trigger alternations in the conditional's trigger – there was a more elegant solution after all!

I will accept this answer now and leave this little journey for anyone else who might be struggling.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I have found a solution using object macros – but it is not very elegant.

This solution returns the users full response (with all the words made lowercase  –with `lowercase` – separated in an array) to the `test` object macro in the `args` variable. The items in this array are enumerated to see whether any of them match an item in the `positives` or `negatives` arrays (which are essentially duplicated substitutions already present in the rivescript 'brain').

If there is a match, the `action` variable is updated to either `yes` or `no` and the loop is broken, if there isn't a match then the `action` variable remains `undefined`. This `action` variable is then returned to the conditional response and evaluated by rivescript to see if it fits any of the conditions.

```
> object test javascript
    let positives = ['yes', 'yeah', 'yep', 'yup', 'yh', 'ya', 'y', 'sure'];
    let negatives = ['no', 'nope', 'na', 'nah', 'pass'];
    var action = 'undefined';
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
      if (positives.indexOf(args[i]) !== -1) {
        action = 'yes'
        break;
      } else if (negatives.indexOf(args[i]) !== -1){
        action = 'no'
        break;
      } else {

      }
    }
    return action;
< object

// In the topic/main section

+ [*] you [*]
- Oh, so we're talking about me now?

+ *
% oh so we are talking about me now
* <call>test <lowercase></call> == no        => Whatever...
* <call>test <lowercase></call> == yes       => This should be fun.{topic=myself}
* <call>test <lowercase></call> == undefined => So, back to the matter at hand...
- So, back to the matter at hand...
```

This seems to work pretty well but I am sure there must be a better solution, even if it is only in cleaning up the object macro itself (maybe there is a way to bring the substitutions into the object macro??).

I am accepting this answer, but if anyone has any alternative suggestions/solutions I would still be happy to hear them.